# Adjust Wordpress function to grab author ID of post

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, points, author

I use a point system plugin for Wordpress. By adding this code to the author.php page:

```
<?php cp_displayPoints($authordata->ID); ?>
```

It will echo `X Points`. This is the points of that respective author. When I add the same code to single.php (post page), it echos the logged in user's points, and if not logged in, it returns blank.

How can I alter this code so that it will function properly on the single.php page too? This would mean that it would **echo the points of the author of that post**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just call [get_the_author_meta](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_author_meta) from within the loop.

So, you just need to test if you have a currently signed in user, if not use the post author instead. Something like this.

```
<?php
if(!$authordata->ID)
  cp_displayPoints(get_the_author_meta('ID'));
else
  cp_displayPoints($authordata->ID);
?>
```

EDIT:

To display only the post author's ID, just use

```
<?php cp_displayPoints(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?>
```

Comment: Can you please explain how I do that so that I can give this a go?

Comment: Excellent this worked perfectly. However, I want this code to display the post author's ID only, never the logged in user's. Can you kindly update your answer with this adjustment?

Comment: Nevermind, that would of course be: <?php cp_displayPoints(get_the_author_meta('ID')); ?> Thank you very much, I have upvoted this and accepted as correct answer.